# Función de crear numero de factura, con año, mes y tres numero que al final de mes se pondrán a 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, poo

estoy haciendo un programa en PHP SQL MVC POO, y necesito una funcin, para crear el numero de factura:
El numero seria asi:

YY-MM-XXX

YY año en 2 cifras
MM Mes en dos cifras
XXX Numero autoincrementable, según el numero de facturas, y cuando se acabe el mes, vuelve a 000

```
public function getNumber()
{
    $date = date_create();
    $p_year = date_format($date, 'y');
    $p_month = date_format($date, 'm');
    $sql = 'SELECT  count(*) as projects FROM project';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $count = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $number = $count['projects'];

    $p_number = $p_year.'-'.$p_month.'-'.$number;

    return $p_number;
}
```

Hasta aquí he podido llegar.

me da el numero pero no se si se puede hacer la condición de volver a 0 cuando cambie el mes en SQL, o bien hacerlo en PHP. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo más simple sería declarar una columna de tipo `auto_increment` y programar un evento para establecer en `1` el valor de ese `auto_increment` el primer día de cada mes y guardar en otra columna la fecha, o el Año-Mes y declarar como PK ambas columnas.

Comment: concuerdo con @A.Cedano tienes que estudiar sobre cron Jobs si usas linux o tareas programadas para mysql creo que puede tener ese alcance que citas.

Answer (score 0):

desoues de lo que me dijeron de hacer un evento, se me ocurrio este pequeño codigo es SQL de donde puedo sacar el numero y me lo inicializa cada mes. gracias, aqui se lo dejo.

`SET @id=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numero); insert INTO numero (id, fecha) VALUES (null, (concat(date_format(now(),"%y-%m-"),(@id+1))));`

aqui seria la entrada de datos, cada vez que inserto un dato nuevo me cambia la unidad.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

CREATE EVENT reset ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2022-06-01 00:00:01' DO truncate table numero;
```

y este es el evento que cada mes me pone el contador a 0.

Gracias por la idea.